# Anchor Tag in React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on terms and conditions page in React application.
The page content has 14 pages in document, so to style the content i just converted the doc as a html file and render it in React component using `ReactHtmlParser` module.
In the content, there are some anchor tags to navigate to the section in the given page.
 ...

I want to know how I can make the anchor tag work in React component.

Some code snippets I am working on:

```
- terms content(text written in html syntax)
text = `
<a href="#child1">terms 1</a>
...
<div id="child1"> term 1 </div>
`
- TermsPage.js
<div>
   {ReactHtmlParser(text)}
</div>
```